# In these sentences can I use "Being" or "to be"?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

Which is better for a woman.... "She loves to be herself instead to show off" or "She loves being herself instead to show off" or "She loves being and not appearing"

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what ***to show off*** means. It's not in any meaningful sense the "opposite" of ***to be oneself*** (to act naturally, in accord with one's own instincts). Some people are natural "show-offs", so it would be quite normal for them to "act naturally" ***and*** "show off" at the same time. Better would be *She loves to be herself rather than **present a false facade***, or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible phrases:

"She loves to be herself instead of showing off."

"She loves being herself instead of showing off."

"She loves to be herself rather than to show off."

The 'of' is required when using instead in this context.  The infinitive form doesn't feel natural, so I would use one of the first two.

Your final sentence "She loves being and not appearing" is grammatical, but I would have no idea what you meant by it.  It sounds like someone who enjoys existing but has a habit of not showing up for parties.

The gender of the subject is irrelevant here.  Any of these would work just as well with He instead of She.